# can we receive message from any email address to exchange server 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, email-server, mailbox

i have one exchange server 2007 in my local network connected to internet.

what i want is to download all emails from specific email address like

```
         myemail@mydomain.com
```

this is catch all email address on domain.

then distribute all emails to local created mail boxes for my exchange server.

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I dont belive there is a POP3 connector in Exchange 2007 although i may be wrong. An option which I have used is to download EFS (http://www.chimera.co.nz/ ) this is basically a POP3 connector for exchange. It can download emails from your catch all and forward them into exchange to distrubute according the *********@domain.com. Small install can be used for free for one domain.

Let me know if you have any issues/questions...

James

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i download this and install.
its works fine and download all messages from pop3 server but these messages are not shown in exchange server, as i also put exchange server name in SMTP server...
i think exchanger is rejecting messages...

Comment: I would check to ensure in the SMTP connector/Hub Transport that you are allowing the exchange server to relay through its self!